# Do Indian Citizens need a transit visa for Thailand?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand

I am an Indian citizen, I am traveling from Guanzhou (China) to Kolkata (India). I have transit at Bangkok airport, the first flight is by Spring airlines and the next is from Spice Jet. So I need to do my own luggage transfer and the transfer time is 4.5hrs. Could anyone kindly tell me do I need a transit visa for that?

Comment: This question is about Thailand in general, so it needs a Thailand tag, not a Bangkok one